# BufferedWriter stops writing to file after a while

Tags: java, android, filewriter, bufferedwriter

I've found a bunch of similiar questions there, but all the proposed solutions already exist in my code, so...

I have the following routine being called from different places in my app:

```
static private void writeToFile(String data) {
    File file = new File("sdcard/output.txt");

    if (!file.exists()) {
        try {
            file.createNewFile();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    BufferedWriter bw = null;

    try {
        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file, true);
        bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.append(new Date().toString() + " " + data);
        bw.newLine();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if(bw != null) {
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes after a while strings stop to be added to a file. I've presumed it's something about syncronization - but once I've succeeded to catch it in debug mode and stepped all over the routine - every statement is executed without any exceptions.

Can you, please, tell what's wrong with my code?

Comment: You are not flushing the content i.e., where is bw.flush() ?

Comment: According to https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#close() "void close () closes the stream, flushing it first."